# Create an array with hash Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, find

I am new at Ruby and Rails and I'm trying to create an array like this:

```
@data =[
        {
          order => {key => value, key1 => value1}, 
          folder => { 0 => {key => value , key1 => value1}, 1 => {key => value, key1 => value}}, 
          document => { 0 => {key => value , key1 => value1}, 1 => {key => value, key1 => value}}
        },

        {
          order => {key => value, key1 => value1}, 
          folder => { 0 => {key => value , key1 => value1}, 1 => {key => value, key1 => value}}, 
          document => { 0 => {key => value , key1 => value1}, 1 => {key => value, key1 => value}}
        },
       ]
```

I have 3 tables, Order, Folder and Document. I have to make a find in Order with certain condition and is going to retrieve some records.
If the find in Order retrieve 3(can be any number) records then I have to make 3 find in Folders and the condition is the Order.id.
Then I have to make a find in Document and the condition is the last Folder.id, this can retrieve many records.

So, I wanna make this so i can send @data to the view and make some foreach for show all the necessary information.

**EDIT:**

Mudasobwa this is what I try:

```
Order.where(conditions).find_each do |order|
   logger.debug(order.id) #first log
   Folder.where(condition order.id).find_each do |folder|
     logger.debug(folder.id) #second log
   end
   Document.where(folder.id).find_each do |doc|
     logger.debug(doc.id) #third log
   end
end
```

With this I am getting the info that I want. 1 order.id then all the folders related with that order.id and all the document related with the last folder.id but I dont know how to create the @data array with all this info, how to join everything.

Comment: You should be able to do this with `Arel`.  Looks like Order has_many Folders and Folder has_many Documents?

Comment: This question is marked as `ruby-on-rails` what means you are on Rails. You mentioned `tables`, hence there is a database behind. Hence you are likely using `ActiveRecord`. So, please show us what have you tried.

Comment: have a look into iterators like `map` or `each_with_object`